# Split a file into multiple gzip files in one line

Tags: awk, split, gzip, cat

Is it possible to split a file into multiple gzip files in one line?

Lets say I have a very large file `data.txt` containing

```
A somedata 1
B somedata 1
A somedata 2
C somedata 1
B somedata 2
```

I would like to split each into separate directory of gz files.

For example, if I didnt care about separating, I would do

```
cat data.txt | gzip -5 -c | split -d -a 3 -b 100000000 - one_dir/one_dir.gz.
```

And this will generate gz files of 100MB chunks under `one_dir` directory.

But what I want is separating each based on the first column.  So I would like to have say 3 different directory, containing gz files of 100MB chunks for A, B and C respectively.

So the final directory will look like

```
A/
  A.gz.000
  A.gz.001
  ...
B/
  B.gz.000
  B.gz.001
  ...
C/
  C.gz.000
  C.gz.001
  ...
```

Can I do this in a 1 liner using cat/awk/gzip/split?  Can I also have it create the directory (if it doesnt exist yet)

Comment: What if you split before gzip? not the other way around

Comment: Why does it have to be in one line? BTW: There are tools named zcat, zless, zgrep and possibly more that transparently operate on compressed files/streams.

Comment: Alex, I guess it doesnt matter? But gzip then split does keep the file sizes more consistent.  @UlrichEckhardt, I guess it doesnt really have to be a one liner, but just thought it be easier if it could.  If its not possible, then I'll take a script or something

Comment: @jhnc Right, sorry let me update the command.  How many is too many?

Comment: Asking for a one liner discourages many people from answering you as it means you favor brevity over robustness, efficiency, portability, clarity and everything else that actually matter in software and so would likely reject a good answer in favor of a "one-liner".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With awk:

```
awk '
   !d[$1]++ {
      system("mkdir -p "$1)
      c[$1] = "gzip -5 -c|split -d -a 3 -b 100000000 - "$1"/"$1".gz."
   }
   { print | c[$1] }
' data.txt
```

Assumes:

- sufficiently few distinct `$1` (there is an implementation-specific limit on how many pipes can be active simultaneously - eg. popen() on my machine seems to allow 1020 pipes per process)
- no problematic characters in `$1`

---

Incorporating improvements suggested by @EdMorton:

- If you have a `sort` that supports `-s` (so-called "stable sort"), you can remove the first limit above as only a single pipe will need to be active.
- You can remove the second limit by suitable testing and quoting before you use `$1`. In particular, unescaped single-quotes will interfere with quoting in the constructed command; and forward-slash is not valid in a filename. (NUL (\0) is not allowed in a filename either but should never appear in a text file.)

```
sort -s -k1,1 data.txt | awk '
   $1 ~ "/" {
      print "Warning: unsafe character(s). Ignoring line",FNR >"/dev/stderr"
      next
   }
   $1 != prev {
      close(cmd)
      prev = $1

      # escape single-quote (\047) for use below
      s = $1
      gsub(/\047/,"\047\\\047\047",s)

      system("mkdir -p -- \047"s"\047")
      cmd = "gzip -5 -c|split -d -a 3 -b 100000000 -- - \047"s"/"s".gz.\047"
   }
   { print | cmd }
'
```

Note that the code above still has gotchas:

- for a path `d1/d2/f`:

  - the total length can't exceed `getconf PATH_MAX d1/d2`; and
  - the name part (`f`) can't exceed `getconf NAME_MAX d1/d2`

Hitting the NAME_MAX limit can be surprisingly easy: for example copying files onto an [eCryptfs](https://www.ecryptfs.org/) filesystem could reduce the limit from 255 to 143 characters.

Comment: I am getting an error:
`split: cannot open 'A/A.gz.' for reading: No such file or directory
split: cannot open 'B/B.gz.' for reading: No such file or directory
split: cannot open 'C/C.gz.' for reading: No such file or directory`.  I see it generated the A, B, C directories though

Comment: I also had to add ; after the system statement.

Comment: `;` is only necessary if you try to type all the commands on a single line - newline and right-brace are statement terminators

Comment: Yea it stops working after 1021 open files on my machine as well

Comment: Assuming the input is very large (billions of rows), sorting may not be that easy

Comment: @user1179317 `sort` uses demand-paging, etc. to be able to efficiently handle massive files. Sorting first is usually the right approach to these sorts of problems as it usually reduces complexity, reduces memory usage, and improves execution speed of the rest of the code.